# Creating AD user based policy that only applies when user logs onto specific computer

Tags: active-directory

Lets say I have machine1, machine2 and machine3. The setup I want should only affect machine3. When I setup computer policy, I can apply it to the machine OU and only have that machine in it so there is no issue there. However when I setup user policy, and it gets applied to the user, the policy will apply itself to any machine the user logs onto, in this example machine1, machine2 and machine3.

My question is how would I setup user policy so that it won't apply to the user when they log into machine1 and machine2, but get applied to the user when they log into machine3? I am on Windows2008 DC environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the GPO loopback processing mode?

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2548.windows-server-understand-user-group-policy-loopback-processing-mode.aspx